# python regex to find the substring from the string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
 <robot generated="20170330 17:19:11.956" generator="Robot 3.0.2 (Python 2.7.13 on win32)">
```

I want to get the value of "generated", but with below code, it doesn't work

```
import re
doc=r'<robot generated="20170330 17:19:11.956" generator="Robot 3.0.2 (Python 2.7.13 on win32)">'
match = re.match(r'generated="(\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+.\d+)',doc)
```

the value of match is none. can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) matches only at the beginning of the string. Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead which matches not only at the beginning, but matches anywhere.

```
>>> import re
>>> doc=r'<robot generated="20170330 17:19:11.956" generator="Robot 3.0.2 (Python 2.7.13 on win32)">'
>>> re.search(r'generated="(\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+)',doc)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1010505d0>

>>> re.search(r'generated="(\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+)',doc).group()
'generated="20170330 17:19:11.956'

>>> re.search(r'generated="(\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+)',doc).group(1)
'20170330 17:19:11.956'
```

See [search() vs. match() from re module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: One nitpicky thing here, is that you use the '.' character for the decimal point in the regex expression. However, regex will see that as *any character*, rather than a literal dot/decimal character, so something like this will also match    '<robot generated="20170330 17:19:11%956" generator="Robot 3.0.2 (Python 2.7.13 on win32)">' (note the percent sign)

Comment: @AbidHasan, Thank you for pointing it out. I updated the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need regular expressions in this case. Here is an alternative idea that uses [`BeautifulSoup` XML/HTML parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) with [`dateutil` datetime parser](https://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
In [1]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: data = '<robot generated="20170330 17:19:11.956" generator="Robot 3.0.2 (Python 2.7.13 on win32)">'

In [4]: parse(BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser").robot['generated'])
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 30, 17, 19, 11, 956000)
```

I find this approach beautiful, easy and straightforward.